# How to hide page extension on web addresses

Tags: url-rewriting

I've noticed that on several web pages e.g. StackOverflow instead of `stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.php` they have `stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you just want to have file-names|tags|titles|categories after the last slash to route semantically to the according file or a hidden path;

If so, you will gain this dependent on the possibilities you have:

---

A) Do you have access to httpd.conf on your Server?

Look out for the **DirectoryIndex**;

**OR**

B) If you are not able to edit httpd.conf, do you have access to **.htaccess** on your server?

Look out if **DirectoryIndex** is already set anywhere, in most cases it won't; so you want to create your own new entry;

---

*TODO:*
Now define the **DirectoryIndex** by letting this reserved word be followed by the filenames you want to have 
been routed to another filename or path/filename

*GODO:*

1. DirectoryIndex
2. [SPACE]
3. *file-name.ending* OR *file-name* OR *tag* OR *title-with-some-words-bond-together*
4. [SPACE]
5. repeat step 3 and 4 until you have a set of catchers to be caught ...
6. at least: add the target of your set by spending a path

*DOJO:*

- **RELOAD** your server
- OR
- **RESTART** if necessary

*EXAM:*

- **DirectoryIndex** *index.html index.htm index.pl index.asp index.jsp index* **/routed/to-path_of/index.php**
- **DirectoryIndex** *ask* **ask.php**

*MOJO:*

This is a quant of what you can achieve; Look out for *pretty-printing* URL's, *apache mod-rewrite*, *DirectoryIndex*, *URI URL hiding*, *domain forwarding* and similar keys you can google for.

In most cases it would have been realized by well-known BLOG/CMS-SoftWare like WordPress, JOOMLA, DruPal, etc. via mod-rewrite, as this is the controlled and preset way if necessary rights are given.

Personally i would recommend to use the simple format of setting **DirectoryIndex** via **.htaccess**, as i explained before, because if you realize your own magic-words you may want to write a script that checks for hash-changes, sniffs history and responds accordingly  to server-errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you program it in DJango, NodeJS, or other WebApp language, they actually parse the URL and do not give you files. Instead it is known as views and map into a certain piece of code.

I suggest your learn NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

It is done through a .htaccess file...